# Issues about installing an R package from Github (non-zero exit status?)

Tags: r

I am trying to install an R package from Github. But I come across the following issue. Does anyone has does how to solve this? Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
devtools::install_github("gregorkb/QregBB")
Downloading GitHub repo gregorkb/QregBB@master
✔ checking for file ‘/private/var/folders/sq/lj12xtts7r9fbjblz_y8q8dh0000gn/T/RtmpSg1adc/remotes18a031a3335d/gregorkb-QregBB-cf0ee46/DESCRIPTION’ (372ms)
─ preparing ‘QregBB’:
✔ checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ...
─ cleaning src
─ installing the package to process help pages
─ saving partial Rd database (14.9s)
─ cleaning src
─ checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts
─ checking for empty or unneeded directories
─ building ‘QregBB_1.0.tar.gz’
installing source package ‘QregBB’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
clang -I"/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include" -DNDEBUG -isysroot /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -I/usr/local/include -fPIC -Wall -g -O2 -c QregBB.c -o QregBB.o
clang -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress -L/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o QregBB.so QregBB.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/.. -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
installing to /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/00LOCK-QregBB/00new/QregBB/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
Error : (converted from warning) /private/var/folders/sq/lj12xtts7r9fbjblz_y8q8dh0000gn/T/Rtmp0W7UGP/Rbuild191c5c79437f/QregBB/man/QregBB-package.Rd:28: All text must be in a section
ERROR: installing Rd objects failed for package ‘QregBB’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/QregBB’
Error: Failed to install 'QregBB' from GitHub:
(converted from warning) installation of package ‘/var/folders/sq/lj12xtts7r9fbjblz_y8q8dh0000gn/T//RtmpSg1adc/file18a07a8be6ad/QregBB_1.0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: I have the same error and loaded, built and checked the package and there are a lot of notes and warnings. You can clone the repository and fix these warnings.

Comment: The error `QregBB-package.Rd:28: All text must be in a section` tells you what you need to know. There is a documentation file for this package that has text illegally placed. You can clone the repository and fix it yourself as @J_F suggested. Specifically, you just need to delete lines 28 and 29 from the file `man/QregBB-package.Rd`

Comment: I left an Issue at the GitHub repo about this (and linking to this discussion)